# Android Maps Library issue

Tags: android, google-maps, libraries

```
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

was working on googlemap integration in my app stuck here.

Cant find these libraries on internet. tried everywhere. Do you have these packages. if yes please share with me or guide me to them. Working on Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This classes are avialable via Google-play-services library. You can find many solutions, how to install it to Android Studio, for example [this one](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)